# How to access App Settings from Azure in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have added an app setting in Azure for my Web Application that I named "SecretKey". When I try to access it in my asp.net mvc app, the key returns null.

```
var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables("SecretKey");
```

I've tried to look up information and I can't find if there is anything I need to do beyond adding the key in Azure. Why is it not able to access it? Is there something I need to do elsewhere in my application to get it to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as follows,

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

and use it as

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecretKey");
     services.AddDbContext<ShelterPZ_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
  }
```

Comment: For this part '.GetConnectionString("SecretKey")', isn't that only if I add it to the Connection String part of Azure instead of the Application Setting part/

Answer (score 0):

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

in your example your are reading env vars but not app settings

Comment: What is the difference between environment variables and app settings? I thought that code accesses the application settings from azure?